# Adicionar todos os elementos do Environment em uma lista de forma automática

Tags: r, lista

Suponha que meu Environment contenha os seguintes objetos (nomes fictícios):

```
abcd # numeric
efgh # dataframe
ijkl # matrix
mnop # character
```

**Meu objetivo**: colocá-los em uma lista de forma automática, sem ter de escrever:

```
mylist<-list(abcd,efgh,ijkl,mnop)
```

Existe uma função capaz de executar isso? Mais precisamente, seria o contrário da função `list2env`.

Comment: Há sim, veja a função `ls()`.

Comment: Tentei várias ações (inclusive com `ls`), mas apenas os nomes dos objetos entram na lista. Quero que os objetos em si fiquem na lista.

Comment: Então deve estar à procura de `get`, quando é só um objeto, e de `mget` para vários objetos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui vai uma maneira de resolver o problema.

Primeiro vou criar um Environment com os objetos descritos na pergunta.

```
set.seed(1234)

e <- new.env()
e$abcd <- rnorm(10)
e$efgh <- data.frame(A = letters[1:5], X = runif(5))
e$ijkl <- matrix(1:24, ncol = 3)
e$mnop <- sample(LETTERS, 10)
```

Agora, obtêm-se os objetos do environment `e` com a função `ls` e depois cria-se a lista desses objetos com `mget`.

```
obj <- ls(envir = e)
lista <- mget(obj, envir = e)
lista
```

Answer (score 1):

Além da função `ls()`, você precisa da função `get()`

```
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(20)
z <- rnorm(30)
```

Exemplo de uso do `get()`:

```
objetos <- ls()
objetos[1]
# [1] "a"
get(objetos[1])
#[1]  1.5730920 -0.1325966  0.1462377 -0.8567735  1.2704741 -0.4335724
#[7] -1.0765247  0.6400620  0.2772769  0.3432856
```

Para todos os objetos do environment numa lista:

```
obj <- ls()
lista = as.list(sapply(obj, get))
```